# How to call super class dictionary and update it - Python

Tags: django, python-3.x

How to call parent class in Python and join two dictionaries

Many thanks in advance.

```
class Base(View):
   title = 'abc'
   slug = 'abc-12'
   def get_context(self, request):
       return {'title': self.title, 'slug': self.slug }

class Logbook(Base)
   mode = 'read' 
   def get_context(self, request)
       # call super class 
       return super().add('mode': self.mode)
       # i want {'title': 'abc', 'slug': 'abc-12', mode: 'read' }

   def get(self, request)
       context = self.get_context(request)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3 you can call parent's class method in the following way:

```py
    def get_context(self, request)
       context = super().get_context(request)
       context.update({'mode': self.mode})
       return context
```